# Simple makefile for C/C++ targets used with arm-linux-gcc

Tags: linux, gcc, arm, cross-compiling, gnu-make

I would like to cross-compile a simple program for ARM architecture using the arm-linux-gcc suite of compilers [arm-linux-gcc (Buildroot 2011.08) 4.3.6].  I've attempted to use a simple makefile for compiling C code, and another simple makefile for compiling C++ code.  For example, my makefile for C code is reproduced below, but it does not create an ELF binary for running on my embedded system.  The host system is x64 GNU Linux.

Here is the listing of my very simple makefile for a C program:

```
CC=arm-linux-gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall
main: test.o 

clean:
    rm -f test test.o
```

The makefile reproduced above only creates an object file with extension .o, and does not create an ELF binary.

I've Googled for a good solution, but I can't seem to find one webpage showing example cross-compile ARM makefiles for both C and C++ programs.  Perhaps an answer to this post could show such examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your `Makefile` and changed the following:

```
test: test.o
```

It worked after this changed and created a binary called `test`. It seems that there is some implicit rule that knows how to link `whatever` if one of its dependencies is `whatever.o`.

Another way is to list the rule explicitly:

```
main: test.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $$
```

This uses the special macros `$@` (which means *target*) and `$$` (which means *dependencies*).

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the GNU make manual (`info make`), [Section 10.2](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules). It has a catalogue of the implicit rules, i.e. the rules where you don't need to explicitly state the commands. Like @GregHewgill thought, the "Linking a single object file" implicit rule builds `N` from `N.o`, but the name must match. Therefore, you can either name your executable like your object file, in which case

```
test:
```

or (more standard because it defines the `all` target)

```
all : test
```

completely suffice. You can also write out the rule explicitly, like Greg Hewgill also described. In this case, the standard rule is:

```
 $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) N.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

Include the LDFLAGS and LDLIBS in your Makefile, it makes life easier for users.

(sic: I think LOADLIBES is really LOADLIBS, and the author missed the `-o`).

Overall, I'd recommend `autoconf` and `automake` instead of hand-rolling makefiles. Gives you a bunch of Makefile features for very little work.